# imagecircleview and textview side by side

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-relativelayout

I want to make imagecircleview and textview lie side by side in xml kotlin android. I have tried this but the textview lies above the imageview. The button is also above the image which I want at the bottom.

I also would appreciate a brief description of the main android layout attributes.[image: user profile ui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageview_profile"
           android:layout_width="120dp"
           android:layout_height="120dp"
           android:src="@drawable/kaleab_profile"
           android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Kaleab Woldemariam"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/previous"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_first" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/circular_shapeAppearance"
            android:id="@+id/imageview_profile"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/name_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Peculiah C. Umesh"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/role_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Mentor Manager"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/about_label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="About"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_below="@+id/about_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec est consequat arcu laoreet consequat non eget quam. Mauris ullamcorper odio id erat pharetra, sed auctor libero tempor. Sed sit amet justo facilisis nisl pharetra mollis. Donec vel felis eget dolor tristique consectetur at nec tortor. Donec eu finibus leo. Fusce non erat semper turpis tincidunt volutpat sit amet sit amet elit."
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/proficiency_label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/about"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Technical Proficiency"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/proficiency"
        android:layout_below="@+id/proficiency_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="JavaScript, Django, Mysql, Android"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Previous" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in **res/values/styles.xml**

```
    <!-- circular picture shape appearance -->
    <style name="circular_shapeAppearance" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>
```

**Note**: I have used `com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView` and shape appearance to make the image view circular. You can replace it with yours.

Comment: almost correct. But I want the textview to be at the side and the mid of the imageview with a space in between.

Comment: can you please provide an image showing the type of layout you want. You can use paint and after taking screenshot update your question with screenshot

Comment: I have also update my answer. I think you should consider ConstraintLayout instead to  avoid multiple layout hierarchy. By the way you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_profile"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_no_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageview_profile"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Kaleab Woldemariam"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Previous" />
</RelativeLayout>
```